# Python: define csv.reader out of the function from which it is called

Tags: python, class

I want to read in data from `'path_to_csv_file'` and print. A piece of code that works is:

```
import csv

class MyClass:

    def f1(self):
        with open('path_to_csv_file', "r") as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            for row in reader:
                print(row)
```

Now, I would like to define the reader out of my printing function. For this I try:

```
import csv

class MyClass:

    def __init__(self):
        with open('path_to_csv_file', "r") as f:
            self.reader = csv.reader(f)


    def f2(self):
        for row in self.reader:
            print(row)
```

But executing `f2`:

```
MyClass().f2()
```

raises the following error:

```
for row in self.reader:
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

How can I define the reader out of my function and yet use it inside? (The reason why I am interested in this is that I will be using the reader in many functions inside `MyClass` and I think it is cleaner to define it only once.)

Comment: Why do you think it's cleaner to define it only once? The reader will be exhausted as you read from it, you'd have to `seek` to the start every time. I'd argue that defining it as a local variable inside the function where you need it is cleaner than having to manage one `reader` across a whole bunch of functions.

Comment: Fair enough! Would you rather use ```with``` or ```open``` + ```close```, inside f1?

Comment: `with` is the recommended pythonic way, so I'd use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The moment, execution comes out of `with`, it will close the file. if you need the file to be open, you have to open it with `open()` and assign it to a variable to close once done. Refer below.

```py
import csv
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.file=open('csv_file', "r")
        self.reader = csv.reader(self.file)

    def f2(self):
        for row in self.reader:
            print(row)
        self.file.close()

MyClass().f2()
```

As Pranav, noted in comments, If you need the file to be open for other functions or for multiple calls of `f1()`, keep `self.file.close()` out of `f2()`, may be in its own function.

Comment: Note that this means you can only call `f2()` once because it closes the file when it's done. If you want to call `f2()` multiple times, don't close the file. Or open the file and create the reader inside `f2()`. Unless the reader is being used elsewhere also, there's really no reason to make it an instance variable instead of a local variable in `f2`